# Проблема с xmltype

Tags: xml, oracle

Есть запрос :

```
SQL> with a as (select '<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>' xml from dual)
  2  select y.* from a, xmltable( '/a'
  3                        passing xmltype(a.xml)
  4                        columns
  5                        b xmltype path 'b') x,
  6                   xmltable('b'
  7                        passing x.b
  8                        columns
  9                        c xmltype path '/')(+) y
 10  ;
C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
```

возвращет две записи, как и ожидалось.

Но если вставить xml во временную таблицу и из нее выбирать данные -

```
SQL> create table tmp_xml as select xmltype('<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>') xml from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select y.* from tmp_xml a, xmltable( '/a'
  2                        passing a.xml
  3                        columns
  4                        b xmltype path 'b') x,
  5                   xmltable('b'
  6                        passing x.b
  7                        columns
  8                        c xmltype path '/')(+) y
  9  ;

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

на выходе null.
Что не так с запросом? 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: В первом запросе тип поля a.xml строковый, в во втором нет. Почему?

Comment: можно вот так 
    with a as (select xmltype('<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>') xml from dual)
    select y.* from a, xmltable( '/a'
                          passing a.xml
                          columns 
                          b xmltype path 'b') x,
                     xmltable('b'
                          passing x.b
                          columns
                          c xmltype path '/')(+) y
результат тотже

Comment: А что означают эти условия соединения?

Comment: (+) перед алиасом x